# Iterate recursion (in a Python Tree)

Tags: python

I've written a Tree class in Python but I'm having issues creating in iterator for it
I want to be able to do

```
phonebook = MyTree()
# Build up tree

for node in phonebook:
    print "%s: %s" % (node.key(), node.data())
```

But it's not working (says generator object doesn't have key() and data()). My Tree class's `__iter__` function returns an iterator class I've created. Here's what I have so far (I know it's wrong and it's not working as it's returning a generator object, since that's what yield does, I want it to remember where it was in the recursion though..so I can't use return) . Basically I just want to return the nodes inorder.

```
class TreeIterator():
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self._current = root
        self._size = size
        self.num_visited = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self._next(self._current)

    def _next(self, curr):
        self.num_visited = self.num_visited + 1
        if self.num_visited == self._size:
            raise StopIteration

        if curr.left is not None and curr.left is not TreeNode.NULL:
            yield self._next(curr.left)

        yield curr

        if curr.right is not None and curr.right is not TreeNode.NULL:
            yield self._next(curr.right)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
if curr.left is not None and curr.left is not TreeNode.NULL:
    yield self._next(curr.left)

yield curr

if curr.right is not None and curr.right is not TreeNode.NULL:
    yield self._next(curr.right)
```

into

```
if curr.left is not None and curr.left is not TreeNode.NULL:
    for x in self._next(curr.left):
        yield x

yield curr

if curr.right is not None and curr.right is not TreeNode.NULL:
    for x in self._next(curr.right):
        yield x
```

It looks like you're `yield`ing an iterator, not a value.  I also think your general approach is way too complicated.

`self._next(curr.left)` returns a generator/iterator.  It contains a bunch of values, not just one, so you need to loop through it.

Comment: This worked, I've seen this before actually but I couldn't get it to work then. Can you explain why this works? I still don't quite understand for x in self_next(curr.left).

Answer (score 1):

Your function `TreeIterator._next()` is a generator function.  This means it returns an *iterator* upon being called.  So you could store the return value of `_next()` and call `.next()` on this return value to get the successive elements of this iterator.  What you do on the other hand is always return a *newly created* iterator in `TreeIterator.next()`, which is never iterated over.  This also explains the error message you get:  You iterator is not returning tree entries, but rather new iterators.

I think the easiest fix for this problem is to drop the `TreeIterator` class completely and copy its `._next()` method to the `.__iter__()` method of your tree class.  Maybe a few things need to be fixed, but I don't know your tree class.

Comment: Thanks I got rid of the class and all of its attributes (which weren't needed). However it still didn't work, robert's answer fixed the main issue.

Comment: @robev: Actually both of those were "main issues".  You needed to fix both of these bugs to make it work.  But glad we could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to iterator over the type, not the instance of the type. Change this:

```
for node in MyTree:
    print "%s: %s" % (node.key(), node.data())
```

to:

```
for node in phonebook:
    print "%s: %s" % (node.key(), node.data())
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I'm doing #2 :)